# Looking for a specific word with regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I've been looking for an answer in SO, but I don't get a straight answer or they're for languages other than JavaScript. I want to use regular expression to look for a class name in a list of classes.

So for example I have this HTML and I want to check if it has the class `hidden` somewhere in the list of classes:

```
<div class="target box hidden"></div>
```

I'm using this JS code, but it doesn't work:

```
// ON CLICK DO THE BELOW:
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    re = /\bhidden\b/gi, //here's the regEx
    i;

for (i = 0, max = divs.length; i < max; i += 1) {
    if (divs.className === 'targets') {
        var targets = divs[i];

        if (targets.match(re)) {
            targets.replace('hidden', '');
        } else {
            targets.className = 'target box hidden';
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I wanna do a show/hide functionality, i.e. if `hidden` class is present then hide element, otherwise show element.

Many Thanks

Comment: `if (divs.className === 'targets') {` will limit you to elements where `class="targets"`, not elements where **one** of the class names is `"targets"`. Also, you're matching `re` against the `div` itself, not its `className`, or even its `outerHTML`

Comment: Do you prefer jQuery ? This can be done very easily using jQuery.

Comment: or you can use `document.getElementsByClassName` function

Comment: @Diode: `document.getElementsByTagName` is not supported in all browsers, i.e. IE7, IE6, etc (you know the deal...) That's why I didn't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function hasClass(ele,cls) {
    return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}

function addClass(ele,cls) {
    if (!this.hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
}

function removeClass(ele,cls) {
    if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
        ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
    }
}
```

Hope the code can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to match the regex against the tag itself. Instead, you should do this:

```
if( targets.className.match(re))
   targets.className = targets.className.replace('hidden','');
```

Additionally, your `divs.className === "targets"` check won't work either, because `divs` is an array, not an element. Remove that `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why not toggle class, here is the snippet i use on all of my plugins, works like a charm:

```
var s = {
    hasClass: function( elem, classname ) {
      var reg = new RegExp( "(^|\\s+)" + classname + "(\\s+|$)" );
      console.log(elem);
      return elem && reg.test( elem.className );
    },

    addClass: function( elem, classname ) {
      if( elem && !s.hasClass( elem, classname ) ) {
        elem.className += " " + classname;
      }
    },

    removeClass: function( elem, classname ) {
      var reg = new RegExp( "(^|\\s+)" + classname + "(\\s+|$)" );
      elem && ( elem.className = elem.className.replace( reg, " " ) );
    },

    toggleClass: function( elem, classname ) {
      var fn = s.hasClass( elem, classname ) ? "remove" : "add";
      s[ fn + "Class" ]( elem, classname );
    }
}
```